# Set a filter programmatically in Mule 3.3

Tags: filter, mule

How do I set a `filename-wildcard-filter` programmatically in Mule 3.3? The `setFilter` method in `org.mule.endpoint.AbstractEndpointBuilder` that was available in Mule 2.x seems to be gone in Mule 3.3.

Comment: I have to set it programmatically in java code using Mule API and not using Mule configuration xml.

Answer (score 1):

The filter which was set in `Endpoint` is modified from Mule 3.x and later.

It is now added as a message processor.

```
 protected List<MessageProcessor> messageProcessors = new LinkedList<MessageProcessor>();
```

So all the message processors including filters can be added to the endpoints. The desired functionality (filter) will be achieved.

Use the methods

```
public void addMessageProcessor(MessageProcessor messageProcessor)
```

or

```
public void More setMessageProcessors(List<MessageProcessor> newMessageProcessors)
```

to add your filters.